# How to install LaTeX package linguex to Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, latex

I would like to write a latex document that contains numbered sentences. I was suggested to use package `linguex` at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504304. How can I install it to Ubuntu?

Comment: I believe this would be `texlive-extra` and `texlive-humanities` which `linguex` is part of. See: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-extra/2013.20131112-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install the `texlive-humanities` package:

```
sudo apt install texlive-humanities
```

It contains the `linguex` LaTeX package (see [the list of files in the package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/texlive-humanities/filelist)).

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 texlive-humanities : Depends: texlive-base (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed

Comment: Did you solve the above problem? If not, please ask a new question with the output of `sudo apt install texlive-base`, and `apt policy texlive-{base,humanities}`.